# How can i create an api endpoint or api with particular domain using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest

I am trying to create a saas and for that, I need to create an API and I am not sure how can I create an endpoint like this https://api.karix.io/message/ here domain is https://api.karix.io and endpoint is the message. I know how to create an API using nodejs but not sure how can I create for the domain-specific.can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please go through this https://github.com/HaneetGH/LoginApi link..

Answer (score 1):

A domain is basically a link to an ip-adress. There are DNS-Servers who transate between the human readable form and the ip.
If you want to run your app on a specific domain you need to purchase that domain (which can be quite costly) and the dns Server will create a link between the domain name and ip adress.

So basically you dont need to do anything in order to create the rest-api for your domain.

Later the request are similiar to this:

- https://api.karix.io/message/
- http://192.168.111.111:80/message <- The ip obviously differs in production

The name of the domain should be accessible in your request-Object atleast in the express framework.

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Comment: The wikipedia pages gives you a good Overview about this topic. [DNS-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). What do you want to know? A domain is just a name for an ip adress and the dns-Server translate between human readable format and computer readable format.